# How to SUM a column, but exclude anything in the column that contains parts of a certain text

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, sumifs

For example, I want to sum everything in a column called **"Dollars"**, but only for the if the corresponding columned called "Description" does not contain parts of the word "Payment". So if it even says "Pay" or "Paym" or "Paymen", it should not include it in the calculation

edit: I've tried

Total Dollars = CALCULATE(SUM('Union'[Dollars]), FILTER ( 'Union', CONTAINSSTRING ( 'Union'[Description], "Payment" ) )

Does not contain doesn't seem to be working... is there a NOT LIKE %Pay% function in dax?

Comment: check SEARCH. You can use the ? and * wildcard characters; use ~? and ~* to find the ? and * characters.
https://dax.guide/search/

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind... I figured it out. For anyone who is curious:

```
Total Dollars = CALCULATE(SUM('Union'[Dollars]), FILTER ( 'Union', NOT CONTAINSSTRING ( 'Union'[Description], "Payment" ) ))
```